# Assured 6 digit random number

Tags: java, scala, random

I have to Generate a 6 digit Random Number. The below is the Code that I have done so far. It works fine but some time its giving **7 digits** in place of **6 digits**.  
The main question is why?  
How do I generate an assured 6 digit random number?

```
val ran = new Random()
val code= (100000 + ran.nextInt(999999)).toString
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `ran.nextInt()` returns a number larger than `900000`, then the sum will be a 7 digit number.

The fix is to make sure this does not happen. Since [`Random.nextInt(n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) returns a number that is less than `n`, the following will work.

```
val code= (100000 + ran.nextInt(900000)).toString()
```

Comment: first you write `ran.nextInt(899999)` then you updated  to `900000`

Comment: @LOL, Yes, I did, because I checked my references and verified the behavior of `Random.nextInt(n)`. The original answer would have excluded the number `999999` itself from ever being chosen, although it would have chosen every *other* six-digit number with equal probability.

Comment: means `ran.nextInt(900000)` will generate from 0 to 899999

Comment: This type of generation would exclude numbers starting with 0 from generated string.

Answer (score 3):

It's because `nextInt()` Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed `int` value between **0 (inclusive)** and the specified value **(exclusive)**

You have to decrease your right border on one.

Answer (score 2):

```
val code= (100000 + ran.nextInt(999999)).toString
```

The problem is `ran.nextInt(999999)` might return number greater than 899999, which would result in 7-digit-number together if you add 100000.

Try change it to

```
val code= (100000 + ran.nextInt(899999)).toString
```

This will ensure your random number to be more than or equal to 100000 and less than or equal to 999999.

Comment: but never equal to 999999

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, [`scala.util.Random`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Random$.html) provides:

[`def between(minInclusive: Int, maxExclusive: Int): Int`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Random.html#between(minInclusive:Int,maxExclusive:Int):Int)

which used as follow, generates a 6-digit `Int` (between `100_000` (included) and `1_000_000` (excluded)):

```scala
import scala.util.Random
Random.between(100000, 1000000) // in [100000, 1000000[
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, for

```
import scala.util.Random
val rand = new Random()
```

consider a vector of `6` random digits,

```
val randVect = (1 to 6).map { x => rand.nextInt(10) }
```

Then, cast the vector onto an integral value,

```
randVect.mkString.toLong
```

This proceeding is general enough to cope with any number of digits. If `Long` cannot represent the vector, consider `BigInt`.

**Update**

Moreover, wrap it into an implicit class, noting that the first digit ought not be zero,

```
implicit class RichRandom(val rand: Random) extends AnyVal {
  def fixedLength(n: Int) = {
    val first = rand.nextInt(9)+1
    val randVect = first +: (1 until n).map { x => rand.nextInt(10) }
    BigInt(randVect.mkString)
  }
}
```

so it can be used as

```
scala> rand.fixedLength(6)
res: scala.math.BigInt = 689305

scala> rand.fixedLength(15)
res: scala.math.BigInt = 517860820348342
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i have to select the merlin2011 answer because he answer first with full explanation, but in my actual code i am using your code.

Comment: @LOL note val in val code=randVect.mkString , thanks for considering this answer.

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti by code inspection cannot disprove it will always give 6 digits; also run brute force test (1 billion runs), all output were 6 digit numbers. Ensure the code used is a copy and paste of that proposed here.

Comment: yes you are right,  7 digits come with any other reason

Answer (score 0):

If you want a random number which can start with zeros, consider this:

```
import scala.util.Random
val r = new Random()
(1 to 6).map { _ => r.nextInt(10).toString }.mkString
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.util.Random
math.ceil(Random.nextFloat()*1E6).toInt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    min=100000
    max=999999
    ans=rand()%(max-min)+min
```