# Why isn't Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999) + 100000) reliable for producing 6 digit numbers?

Tags: javascript, math, random

I've looked at some other questions, but they all have disjointed and [confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23623127/1082555) answers.

I want to have a random 6 digits, which most of the time this scripts work - it does however also produce 7 digit numbers about 20% of the time.

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999) + 100000)
```

**My questions:**

1. Why?
2. Correct way of avoiding this?

*Please don't suggest using substring or something similar as it is a bit of a hack*

Comment: It _should_ only do it 1/10th of the time

Comment: It may be helpful to write a generic `randInt` method, and use that rather than inline arithmetic. You can find an example implementation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

Comment: @Alnitak As with all good things, I'm currently thinking my 20% is a little to generous, more like 40% in the last run I did :/

Comment: @tim.baker it really should only be 10% (assuming correct random distribution).  The random part of your range is 0..999,998 instead of 0..899,999 and so it's only when you hit the bit that exceeds 900,000 (which _should_ be 10% of samples) that you end up with seven digits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a simple calculation range error.  NB: text below uses `[` and `]` to represent an *inclusive* range and `(` or `)` to represent an *exclusive* range.

To get the range [100000, 999999] which in integer math is equivalent to [100000, 1000000) you need to get a number in the range [0, 900000) and then add 100000, e.g.

```
Math.floor(900000 * Math.random()) + 100000
```

The factor is 900000 rather than 899999 because the `Math.random()` function produces numbers in the range [0, 1), i.e. not including 1 itself.

Comment: It should be noted that the Random Number Generator in many JavaScript engines isn't all that good.  There is a popular replacement here: https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom

Answer (score 1):

well the problem is in your math.

`Math.random` produces a float from 0.0 to 1.0 . In the worst case you multiply 1.0 with 999999 and add another 100000 . this results in 1099999.0 (for the biggest case).

this line should always produce a 6-digit number

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 899999) + 100000)
```

Comment: there's a problem with your math, too - the max value from the OP's original code is 1,099,998 ... ;-)

Comment: Aghh! I can't see it though... ?

Comment: @Alnitak No it's not. Type `Math.floor(1 * 999999 + 100000)` into your JS console.

Comment: @MikeC that's the problem - `Math.random()` by definition never produces exactly 1.0

Comment: and the multiplication factor is wrong too (I didn't spot that before!)  It's 900000, not 899999, for the same reason

Comment: @Alnitak [You're right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), my mistake

Comment: FWIW, the code above _will_ only produce 6 digit numbers, but the max value is 999,998 instead of 999,999